# How to make a square dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a square dropdown menu that look something like this: 
[image]

What I've tried:

```
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Class View <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Student 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Student 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Student 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Student 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Student 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Student 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Student 7</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

What I get :

[image]

Can someone give me some hints, or help me make this happend ?

[`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/a2nzdLy3/)

Comment: What CSS are you using ? Also do you have a link ?

Comment: Are you using a framework like bootstrap? Can you create a jsfiddle and show us what CSS you've tried?

Comment: Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/a2nzdLy3/)

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823871/how-to-make-a-square-button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823871/how-to-make-a-square-button)

Comment: I already got the answer to that. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
.btn {
   border-radius: 0;
}
```

If you want to customize your select to look like the one you posted (with custom arrows, etc), you should probably use something like [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) or [Selecter](http://formstone.it/components/Selecter/demo/index.html)