# How to style buttons for calculator HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html

Using your help, I styled the number buttons, but I want to make the +, -, * the color red

Code at: https://ghostbin.com/paste/68w8d

Comment: is it a regular `<button></button>` ?

Comment: @Angel ofDemons I added the code through a link. You can check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *select* the `<input type = button>` you can use this code to set a background color

`input[type=button] {
  background-color:green
}`

With this you can also set width /height anything you want. OR you can give them all a class and style by class.

`<input type="button" class="myButtons">`

css:

`.myButtons { background-color:green }`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Did this solve your problem or is there anything else I overlooked? I'll be glad to try to help you out! @MLCLOUD

Comment: To style buttons all you need is `input[type=button]` or `input[type=submit]` etc @MLCLOUD

Comment: Sorry was away for a moment. Did you fix it already? And what do you need an example of @MLCLOUD ?

Answer (score 0):

to make a square button 
take a look at this question : 
[How to make a square button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823871/how-to-make-a-square-button)

and if you whant to color them you can choose the color that you want and copy the given code : 
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

for example : I choose this color

```
background: rgb(226,226,226); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%, rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%, rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%, rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e2e2e2', endColorstr='#fefefe',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

this is the result 
http://jsfiddle.net/J8zwC/361/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is try and learn CSS through some kind of tutorial website, and you'll pick up the techniques you need along the way. I would advise something like W3Schools, but just Google *CSS Tutorial* and something will certainly come up.

With regards to having them 'Square and coloured', try something like:

```
.button_class {
    background: white;
    height 2em;
    width: 2em;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Just change the `background` property to whichever colour you need. If you want to be more specific you can use hex codes: `#RRGGBB`, where RR is the hex value (between 00 and FF, which is 0 and 255 in decimal) for red, BB is the hex value for blue, and GG is the hex value for green. The hex value system is basically a way to mix different amounts of the prime colours to achieve any of the 16.8 million available colours.

#### Update

For the square look on the buttons, use the `border-radius: 0` property.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: I am currently learning CSS and I know how to style but I wasn't sure how to style buttons.

Comment: Just use the same properties as you normally would. When you learn more about it you'll learn which elements have their own special properties, but you shouldn't need any for this

Comment: I can't seem to achieve the square look, only the color!

Comment: Do you mean it's rectangular, or that the corners are rounded?

Comment: i want to the cornered to be squared not rounded